# Reading serial numbers with Python

Tags: python, lidar

My goal is to read the serial number of the L515 with my Python code.
I'm am absolute beginner.

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs # I would like to work with this library

pipeline = rs.pipeline()

number = rs.camera_info.asic_serial_number

rs.get_option(number)
```

I did have a look into the `pyrealsense2` documentation
(https://intelrealsense.github.io/librealsense/python_docs/_generated/pyrealsense2.camera_info.html#pyrealsense2.camera_info.asic_serial_number)

I could not find any hints on how to get the number in the camera info modules. With this code above the error message I get is :

```
 rs.get_option(number)
AttributeError: module 'pyrealsense2' has no attribute 'get_option
```

If someone could guide me through this - Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  For starters, please include a [mcve] and indicate what issues you are getting.  The above error clearly indicate that there is no attribute under that name

Comment: According to the documentation, `get_option()` needs to be used with a sensor or interface. Thefore, the syntax would be like this: `your_sensor.get_option(number)`. Not sure about the parameter. This documentations are rather sparse. Reference: https://intelrealsense.github.io/librealsense/python_docs/_generated/pyrealsense2.options.html?highlight=get_options#pyrealsense2.options.get_option

Comment: As per the pyrealsense2 lib documentation, "get_option" function is not existing, not sure why you planned to use this after going through the documentation